# Tag Map for Photo.SE

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion

I've just made a map of tags for **Photography - StackExchange**.

In short: tag size is related to tag popularity and edges are related to tag co-occurrences in questions. Different colors were used for further clarity, to distinguish tag groups, which co-occur a lot.

For me it looks as a (nomen omen) "snapshot" of topics and scope of this SE site. So if you want to you it in any way to promote Photo.SE - feel free!

Also, if you have comments how to improve its usefulness or niceness to the community, I would appreciate them. (Also, any aesthetic pointers are more than welcome - it's not my strongest side.)

[image: Tag Map for Stats.SE]

### Links:

- [An entry for StackExchange vis competition at Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow/prospector#211) (please vote if you like it :), it ends on Nov 3, 2012)
- [Recipe, code and images at GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange) (e.g. tweak the plot to your taste; feel invited to co-develop)